# Do I need any equipment for charging US electronic devices in Israel?

Tags: usa, electronic-items, israel, power

This summer, I will be going with a tour group for two weeks around Israel. I live in the U.S. Will I need any special equipment for plugging in devices?

(I found online that Israel uses H-type plugs and America uses A-type, but is this true also in tourist hotels?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Israel also uses 220V unlike the 110V you use in USA, so you need to be sure your devices can handle that (nowadays many can) or use an adapter that can transform the current.

And even tourist-y hotels will probably only offer the sockets used locally, else they would have to offer a wide variety of sockets to cater to the needs of their guests from all over the world.

Comment: Quite a few hotels have "universal" sockets that accept a variety of different plugs, including EU, UK, US, AU... That's however still a minority, and it's difficult to count on it. However, nearly all hotels will have adapters available (cheaper hotels may sell or rent them or ask for a deposit, more expensive hotels will provide them for free on request).

Answer (score 1):

Most electronic devices can us 110-240 Volts, which covers most of the world, including Israel. Check the label.

Though Israel uses the weird type H, a European 2-pin plug (type C) easily plugs into an Israeli socket. An adapter (type A to type C) is easy to find, in the USA, Europe and Israel.